# No KeyValueTextOutputFormat?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

What is a corresponding OutputFormat class of KeyValueTextInputFormat? I want to put some delimiter between key and value in the output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TextOutputFormat will write `<Text, Text>` pairs out.

You can define the delimiting character (which defaults to tab) by setting the `mapred.textoutputformat.separator` property. Note this property has changed to `mapreduce.output.textoutputformat.separator` in 2.0.0+ hadoopd